# Why ES6 imports all functions from a module, and not only the requested one?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

When importing a function from a module, all exported functions are imported although only one was imported in main.js:

someModule.js:

```
export let print_a = (function(){
    console.log('Hello from a')
})();

export let print_b = (function(){
    console.log('Hello from b')
})();
```

main.js:

```
import { print_a  } from './someModule.js';
```

index.html:

```
...
<body>
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Since I have imported only print_a from someModule.js I expected to  get output:

"Hello from a"

Instead I have got the output:

"Hello from a"

"Hello from b"

Why print_b is called although it was not imported in main.js?

Comment: Javascript needs to evaluate `someModule.js` to know what is in it. You are calling functions in that file with side effects. So you will see those side effects. If you don't want those functions evaluated when the file is read, remove the `()` and call them after import. As it is you are setting the value of `print_a `  to `undefined` because that's what is returned by the function call.

Comment: Because that is the way the specification says to deal with a JavaScript MIME type in the browser. Retrieve the file and parse (the entire file) it immediately. As Mark says, if you don't want the side effects construct your module accordingly.

Comment: [Reference](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-module-semantics-runtime-semantics-evaluation) - the "moduleItemList" is the set up import, export statements and the module body.

Answer (score 1):

What chucksmash said is true. These are IIFEs. Have you considered using functional declarations and then exporting using 'require' syntax like so:

```
module.exports = function print_a(){
  console.log('Hello from a')
});


module.exports = function print_b(){
   console.log('Hello from b')
});
```

Alternatively, you can define the functions and then just export them explicitly in a single statement like so (instead of assigning each function to module.exports individually):

```
module.exports = { print_a, print_b }
```

And I would use the require syntax to import the module
into the JS file that will be invoking these functions:

```
const { printA, printB } = require('./someModule.js')
```

The major difference between require and import , is that require will automatically scan node_modules to find modules, but import , which comes from ES6, won't. Most people use babel to compile import and export , which makes import act the same as require

Answer (score 0):

These are both [IIFEs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression), immediately invoked function expressions. You've executed an IIFE and assigned its value to `print_b`, but you've not imported `print_b`. You can test this by trying to do `console.log(print_b)`.

Comment: I think the OPs point was that the entire module file is read and executed. Which is true. The OP's terminology is sort of redundant when it comes to the term "import" :-)